# How to add buttons in cycle in Android

Tags: android

I add one button to my application

```
LayoutParams lpView = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Button");
        linLayout.addView(btn, lpView);
```

But actually I don't know how much buttons will I have, how to generate it in cycle. I mean, how to do different name:

```
Button btn1 = new Button(this); 
Button btn2 = new Button(this); Button
btn3 = new Button(this);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "different name"

Comment: Well, the loop is written in Android using keywords FOR or WHILE. You can use any Collection to remember the created buttons or you can access them directly on layout with getChildAt(index). I really cannot figure out that kind of difficulties are we facing here. Please explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plain Java array of buttons:

```
Button[] mButtonsArray = new Button[10];
        for (Button b : mButtonsArray) {
            b = new Button(this);
            linLayout.addView(b, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use a Button array.

```
Button[] btnarray = new Button[length];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way:

> ```
>  public void GenerateButtons()
>     {
>     LinearLayout m_ll_layout;
>     public static ArrayList<Button> m_arr_btn= new ArrayList<Button>();
>     RelativeLayout p_rl_layout=new RelativeLayout(this);
>     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = null;
>     layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);          
>     m_ll_layout = new LinearLayout(m_context);
>     m_ll_layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
>     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
>     {
>         Button m_btn = new Button(m_context);
>         m_btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(90, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
>         m_btn.setText("Button");
>         m_btn.setId(i);
>         m_btn.setOnClickListener(OnClickBtn_TimeListener);
>         m_arr_btn.add(m_btn);
>         m_ll_layout.addView(m_btn);         
>     }
>     layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
>     p_rl_layout.addView(m_ll_layout, layoutParams);
> }
> ```